# bind9 equivalent to dnsmasq's resolv-file option

Tags: linux, dns, bind, dnsmasq

I am currently using dnsmasq as a DNS forwarder for 1.1.1.1, but I need to switch to bind9.
*/etc/resolv.conf* points to localhost.

In my */etc/dnsmasq.conf* I have  the following:

```
resolv-file=/run/resolv.conf
```

This file is a symlink to another file containing, for example:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

I can achieve the same result in bind with this (in my *named.conf.options*) :

```
forwarders {
    1.1.1.1;
};
```

I was wondering, though, if there is a way to force bind9 to use an external file to get the forwarders' list, pretty much like *resolv-file* option does with dnsmasq.
I have been unable to find anything relevant to this in [bind9 manual](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.21/).
If that is not the case, is there a disadvantage to use bind9's way to set forwarders compared to dnsmasq's?